# Multiplying Intervals

Tags: java

I'm trying to create this method, but for some reason it isn't working...

```
public static Interval multiply(Interval x, Interval y) {
   int min = Math.min(x.lo * y.lo, x.hi * y.hi, x.hi * y.lo, x.hi * y.hi);
   int max = Math.max(x.lo * y.lo, x.hi * y.hi, x.hi * y.lo, x.hi * y.hi);
   return new Interval(min, max);
```

It has something to do with the Math.min/Math.max, but I looked it up, so I'm not sure how I'm not using it correctly??

Comment: The `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions only take two arguments. Is this you real code? If so, its not compilable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using Joda?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but:

```
public static Interval multiply(Interval x, Interval y) {
   int min = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(x.lo * y.lo, x.hi * y.hi), x.hi * y.lo), x.hi * y.hi);
   int max = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(x.lo * y.lo, x.hi * y.hi), x.hi * y.lo), x.hi * y.hi);
   return new Interval(min, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy, but since the multiplication of an interval never uses its own high and low, by definition the low and high result will be low*low and high*high, as long as the numbers are positive. As long as you know definitively the number are always positive (like you are using time), you could do this:

```
public static Interval multiply(Interval x, Interval y){
   return new Interval(x.lo*y.lo, x.hi*y.hi);
}
```

If you did not know that for sure, you could try this:

```
public static Interval multiply(Interval x, Interval y){
   int min = (x.lo*y.lo <= x.lo*y.hi) ? x.lo*y.lo: x.lo*y.hi;
   min = (min <= x.hi*y.lo) ? min: x.hi*y.lo;
   min = (min <= x.hi*y.hi) ? min: x.hi*y.hi;
   int max = (x.lo*y.lo >= x.lo*y.hi) ? x.lo*y.lo: x.lo*y.hi;
   max = (max >= x.hi*y.lo) ? max: x.hi*y.lo;
   max = (max >= x.hi*y.hi) ? max: x.hi*y.hi;
   return new Interval(min, max);
}
```

There may be a better way to accomplish those comparisons using bitwise operators, but I have no idea how.